# _.map and _.zip javascript syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

Using undescore.js:

```
(_.map(_.zip([v,xs]),function(rs){return {a:rs[0],x:rs[1]}}))
```

gives me a syntax error

> Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 34 of the expression [(*.map(*.zip([v,xs]),function(rs){return {a:rs[0],x:rs[1]}}))] starting at [{return {a:rs[0],x:rs[1]}}))].

More context

```
<rect  ng-repeat="z in (_.map(_.zip([v,xs]),function(rs){return {a:rs[0],x:rs[1]}}))" x="{{z.x.x(z.a)}}%" y="{{z.y.y(z.a)}}"  width="{{z.x.w(z.a)}}" height="{{z.x.h(z.a)}}" style="fill:rgba({{z.x.s.r}},{{z.x.s.g}},{{z.x.s.b}},{z.x.s.a}})"/>
```

Comment: I don't get a syntax error when I paste that code.

Comment: I suspect this error is coming from Angular, not Javascript.

Comment: I did some googling, that's definitely an Angular.js error message.

Comment: Thanks, I move the code in the controller, now it's no more error. Btw, touching a comment which has been used to build other comments is just not fair

Comment: If a comment was based on a misunderstanding, we'll often delete it once someone points out the error, to avoid cluttering the comment area.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use these methods inside of an Angular binding. I recommend you use them to process the data in your controller and using ng-repeat to iterate over the processed data. Alternatively you can make Angular filters that wraps around them, if you use them very often.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('lodashUsageController', lodashUsageController);


function lodashUsageController($scope) {
  $scope._ = _;
  $scope.list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  $scope.even = function(item) {
    return {
      val: item,
      isEven: item % 2 === 0
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="lodashUsageController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in _.map(list, even) track by $index">
        {{item.val}} - {{item.isEven}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As Jon Snow has mentioned that it's not recommended to use lodash functions directly inside of the ng-repeat.

That being said, there is a way to do it. I have created this [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/budimuruje/1/edit?html,js,console,output) to demonstrate it.

Basically, what you need to do is to expose "_" as a $scope variable (so angular binding can access it).

```
$scope._ = _;
```

You can't have direct anonymous functions inside of the binding, try to create them in the controller and then access it from the ng-repeat.

HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="lodashUsageController">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in _.map(list, even) track by $index">
    {{item}}
  </li>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function lodashUsageController($scope) {
  $scope._ = _;
  $scope.list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  $scope.even = function(item) {
    return item % 2 === 0;
  }
}
```